# Plotting continuous lines from a matrix on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I am trying to plot this array:

```
A=[

   1     1     3    3     3     3;

   2     3     2    2     2     2;

   3     2     1    1     1     1]
```

where the axis X must be the index of each column (1,2,3,4,5,6) and the axis Y must be the numbers on each column of the matrix, so I will have three line of plotting. The values  So, for the value "1" I will have one continuous line plot along the X axis, for the value "2" other continuous line and another for "3".

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I made a figure for the example above. I want matlab make this kind of graphics from a huge matrix.

[image]

I am having problens on plotting this matrix

[image]

The results is:

[image]

Please, if you compare the graphics with the matrix, it isn't the same as debería ser.  If you see de E(4,1)=10 in Y=1, then you see the same number on Y=2, i can say that the number 10 goes from the row = '4' to row = '10' , but comparing with the graphics isn't the same (like I want).

Comment: @Dan To be absolutely general, it would be `plot(A.')`

Comment: Thanks. But, i have to make that axis Y be descending. @Dan

Comment: Please, someone can explain why this way works? @LuisMendo

Comment: @OscarSantacruz Well your data isn't descending. So I think you need to restate your problem and maybe include an example of what you want the plot to look like

Comment: @OscarSantacruz From `help plot`: "PLOT(Y) plots the columns of Y versus their index". So `plot(Y.')` plots the rows of Y versus their index.

Comment: @Dan i put the way i want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot the rows of `A` and make the y axis descending:

```
plot(A.')
axis ij
```

Explanation:

- From `help plot`: "PLOT(Y) plots the columns of Y versus their index". So plot(Y.') plots the rows of Y versus their index.
- From `help axis`: "AXIS IJ puts MATLAB into its 'matrix' axes mode. The coordinate       system origin is at the upper left corner. The i axis is vertical and is numbered from top to bottom. The j axis is horizontal and is numbered from left to right."

---

If you want to plot in which row a given number is for each column (according to your edited question):

```
[E_sort ind] = sort(E);
plot(ind.')
axis ij
```

This works if there are no gaps in the set of numbers contained in `E`.

Comment: Can you solve the problem i am having right now, edit the problem above!

Comment: This is a different question! If I understood correctly what you want now: see second part of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't understood what is the mening of "ind"

Comment: It's just an indexing variable. It gives the index of the row where each number is, for each column. See the documentation of `sort` by typing `help sort` or `doc sort`.